# what oracle data dictionary view can be used to decribe types defined in a plsql package?

Tags: oracle, plsql, data-dictionary

What oracle data dictionary view can be used to describe types / subtypes defined in a plsql package?

Comment: One way to go is enable the user_identifiers parameter: ALTER SESSION SET PLSCOPE_SETTINGS='IDENTIFIERS:ALL';  / Then, you need to recompile all packages you want to check (I know, it sucks) / then, query the USER_IDENTIFIERS view. (it will contain a VERY usefull column named usage. Check that view, and it might contain what you need.

Answer (score 1):

If all of the types uses are used explicitly, meaning now using execute immediate, then you can look at dba_dependencies to see what types a PL/SQL stored procedure uses.